# What is the difference of the word "me" in these two sentences?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

What are the grammatical terms to describe the two different ways of using the words "me" in these two sentences?

1. This is me
2. Kill me

I found out that there is a difference between these two in another language and they use two different forms of the noun "I" in these two cases. What are the linguistic terms to explain the difference?

Comment: There is no difference. But historically we wrote "this is I", not "this is me".

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. What I'm saying is, there IS a difference and I don't know how to explain it. Maybe the difference is not clear in English. But linguitically there is a difference.

Comment: My point is that today's English doesn't recognize that difference although a few decades ago it did.

Comment: Google the word *copula* for an explanation of how it used to work (and how it still works in some other languages)

Comment: Oh then, can you explain that difference? Why was it "I" instead of me in the first sentence, and why the 2nd sentence has always been "me"? and why did it change?

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try.

Comment: In 'Kill me', _me_ is the object of the verb. In 'It is I', 'This is I', _I_ is effectively the subject.

Comment: The word `I` and `me` means exactly the same thing. However due to english grammar they are to be used in different instances depending on how the noun, ahem, pronoun is being used. If you mix up the words `I` and `me` in your speaking, you'll sound weird and foreign. For example, if a noun or pronoun is being used in a possessive manner, then the "preposition word" or "article word" that goes before it, will have to be different. For example in some sentences you'll have to use **"of X"** where X is a noun, and in others you'll have to use **"as X"** depending on how the noun is being used.

Comment: I upvoted one comment and I would have posted an answer if I knew. For those commenting, kindly read the question body (=NOT only the header). <title> Yang asked about the grammatical terms.

Answer (score 1):

1. The "me" in your first sentence is a **subject complement**.

   Normally, "I" is a *nominative pronoun*, which means it has the role of *subject*. And normally, "me" is an *accusative pronoun*, which means it has the role of *an object*.

   In your first sentence, "this" is the subject, and by definition a noun after "is" is a part of the subject too because of the *copula* "is". We say this third word "completes the subject", so we call it a *subject complement*. Now, since it's a subject, and "I" is our nominative pronoun, we should expect the sentence "*This is **I***", as it is in other languages, and as it used to be in English. But nowadays we almost always use "me" as a subject complement. Saying "This is I" or "It is I" these days is laughably formal.
2. The second "me" is the **direct object** of "kill". This follow normal rules of grammar as "me" is the standard accusative pronoun, so it's no surprise to find it in the role of object.